# How to press key and do a function in the background of tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a program that make a optional copy, for example when pressing a key like num 1 which paste something you chose in program  or num 2 which paste something you chose in program..
but that program should work in background (minimized) but it doesn't work..

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

first = ''
second = ''

root = Tk()
#root.withdraw()
ttk.Label(root, text="1st copy").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=3, sticky='w')

copy1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=36)
copy1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)

ttk.Label(root, text="2nd copy").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=3, sticky='w')

copy2 = ttk.Entry(root, width=36)
copy2.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)

savebutton = ttk.Button(root, text='save')
savebutton.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='e')
savebutton.config(command=lambda:save())

def save():
    global first, second
    first = copy1.get()
    second = copy2.get()

def BuClick(x):
    global first, second

    root.clipboard_clear()
    if x == 1:
        root.clipboard_append(first)
    else:
        root.clipboard_append(second)
    root.update()



root.bind('1', lambda x = 1:BuClick(1))
root.bind('2', lambda y = 2:BuClick(2))
```

so how I can make it work in background ??
Thanks in advance..

Comment: start a thread for working paralel to ui

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyboard like this.

```
import keyboard as kb
def call_back():
    pass
kb.add_hotkey("shift+1",call_back,args)
kb.wait()
```

This, however, would get called even if the focus is not on your app(if you were using a different one).

Comment: I'm afraid, I think it doesn't work could you give it me with my code ?

Comment: Actually I didn't work or maybe I didn't use it correctly could you paste it in my code and then give it to me .. I'm sorry for being stressful !

Answer (score 0):

In Tkinter to do something in the background you should use the [after](https://riptutorial.com/tkinter/example/22870/-after--) method. This puts and event onto the UI event queue that calls your function after some delay. In this case `root.bind('<Key-1>', lambda: root.after_idle(BuClick(first)))` should do it. This schedules a call to `BuClick` once the event queue is idle (ie: not processing other UI events like mouse movement or window redrawing etc).

Comment: I'm afraid, I think it doesn't work could you give it me with my code ?